# Java - Can constants store and calculate other variables within them?

Tags: java, constants, final

**TL;DR at bottom**

I'm currently taking Programming 1 at my community college, and I just got feedback on a lab I had turned in a few weeks ago. Supposedly, there's one area where I made a mistake, but I'm not sure it's mistake.

A bit of context: In our lab, we were supposed to write a program that would collect and calculate the user's total money earned over a number of hours, and then deduct the requisite percentages of income tax, money spent on goods, bonds, etc. from the income.

Part of the lab's instructions required that we "define values for tax, clothes, school supplies, saving bonds, and parent saving bonds as 'constant' (which was defined as a `final` at this point in class)."

In order to save space, I decided to go ahead and calculate the total values of each item within the constant itself, instead of putting just the percentages in the constants and calling them later.

According to my professor, however, this choice was wrong because it did not declare my constants correctly. Supposedly, the only things that should be stored in the constants are pure numbers (ie, just the percents); by trying to include and calculate variables in my initialization, I effectively broke my code, seeing as the constants would forever have the first calculations locked in place, and would be unable to calculate new numbers/variables if the code was run again (note: I just now ran the program through a loop to see if this was true, and it still worked correctly).

If I'm wrong, so be it, I still learned something in the end. But if I'm not, I'd like to know.

Here's the code in question; what are your thoughts?

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import java.text.DecimalFormat;

public class Lab2C  
{
    static DecimalFormat form = new DecimalFormat("$#0.00");

public static void main (String[] args) 
    {
        //Declare variables
        String input;
        String output;
        double payRate=0;
        double hourWrk=0;
        double income;

        //"for" loop to collect user input
        for (int count=0;count!=2;count++)
        {
            if (count==0)
                {input=JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please enter your hourly pay: ");
                 payRate=Double.parseDouble(input);
                }
            else if (count==1)
                {input=JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please enter your total hours "
                        + "worked for the past month: ");
                 hourWrk=Double.parseDouble(input);
                }
        }

        //Calculate and output final numbers

        income = payRate*hourWrk;

        //Declare the constants
        final double taxed = income-(.14*income);        // <---------
        final double cloth = .1*taxed;                   //The portion of code my
        final double supp = .01*taxed;                   //prof took issue with
        final double myBond = .25*taxed;                 // <---------
        final double prntBond = .5*myBond;

        output = 
                "Total Income (before tax): " + form.format(income) + "\n" +
                "Total Income (after tax): " + form.format(taxed) + "\n" +
                "----------------------------------------" + "\n" +
                "       Funds spent on Clothes: " + form.format(cloth) + "\n" +
                "       Funds spent on School Supplies: " + form.format(supp) + "\n" +
                "       Funds spent on Savings Bonds: " + form.format(myBond) + "\n" +
                "       Parent's funds spent on Savings Bonds: " + form.format(prntBond) + "\n" +
                "----------------------------------------" + "\n" +
                "Total Remaining Funds: " + form.format(taxed-(cloth+supp+myBond+prntBond));

        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, output);
    } 
}
```

**TL;DR** - Are there any major issues with how I initialized/used my constants?

Comment: I dont see constants in your code. Constants should be 'final static' variables declared at class level.

Comment: Yeah, I wasn't sure if they're technically considered "constants" or not, but the `final double` variables were how our professor wanted us to define our constant variables (an oxymoron, I know) at this point in class.

Comment: @JoshMac read the answer update

Comment: The way you used it are not 'constants'. Yet neither is the code wrong. Some IDEs have an option to look at your code and add `final` if possible. For lambdas Java even now uses a term 'effectively final'. It is debatable whether Java really has the notion of a constant.

Comment: Your code is quite good. There's no issue with your variables. In fact, using final variables (write-once variables) might be considered a best practice! Your prof is likely confusing them with C or C++ static variables which do keep their value forever, even across function calls. It is not unusual for professors to be not entirely proficient in the languages they teach.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A "constant", in computer programming terms, is a value that is known at compile time, based entirely on the program's source code. This value can be the result of some calculation, but the only inputs allowed are other constants. For example, you could define a constant with value `2 * Math.PI`.

In Java, constants are declared as `static final` fields of a class - that is, outside all methods, such as where you put `form`.

What you declared are local variables that cannot be recalculated, not constants.

Now, you might be wondering how what I just said could be compatible with the fact that your program worked fine when run in a loop. The answer lies in Java's variable scope rules. Your `final` variables are declared inside the body of the loop, which means that their scope is confined to that loop body. Moreover, it is confined to *a single iteration of* that loop body. Your loop runs once, creates all these new local variables and assigns values to them, finishes the first run, *and throws those variables away*. When it runs again, it's not reusing the same variables, it's creating a whole new batch. This new batch can, of course, be initialized just like the first batch was, so the program continues to work.

Comment: Okay, so loops release variables declared inside them the same way a called method releases the memory of its local variables when done? (We just learned about methods apart from main today, hence the question)

Comment: @JoshMac Yes. And so do `if` blocks, `try/catch/finally` blocks (which I'd guess you haven't learned yet), and really pretty much anything besides a class definition that goes inside a pair of `{` and `}`. You can even add a pair of curly braces like that without a loop at all, just to create a new scope for variables. When the program reaches the closing `}`, the variables between it and the matching `{` go away.

Comment: Huh, interesting! I sort of knew that (I at least knew I could re-use variables declared in loops), but I didn't know why that happened, or that it happened elsewhere. And yeah, `try/catch/finally` hasn't been touched on yet, but my curiosity is piqued now that I know that it exists...

Answer (score 2):

I think your teacher was mainly complaining about you having literal values in your code. The idea is that you define your literal constants ahead of time to avoid having to repeat them in your code. 
See the following:

```
static final double INCOME_TAXE_RATE = .14;
static final double CLOTHING_TAXE_RATE = .1;
...
public static main(String[] args)
```

and then you can use them as follow:

```
double taxed = income-(INCOME_TAXE_RATE * income);      
double cloth = CLOTHING_TAXE_RATE * taxed;              
...
```

The other advantage of declaring your literal constant is the fact that if you need to update them, you have one place in your code where you can do so. This makes your code more readable and maintainable.

Also it is good to node that Java doesn't support the concept of object immutability, it doesn't directly support constant. The static modifier cause the the variable to be available without loading an instance of the class. And the final modifier makes the variable to unchangeable. This olds true only for primitive data type. A Final object, can still be modified.

Answer (score -2):

It's good practice to use `final` keyword with fields wherever you can, to avoid problems with multithreading and you defined it normal. Your professor meant that you won't be able to reassign variables with `final` keyword. But in this case you don't need it, so it's fine.

Comment: Okay, so a variable with `final` cannot have its own assigned value rewritten, but any values/variables assigned to the `final` variable at initialization can have their own values changed, which can affect the `final` variable's output?

Comment: @JoshMac No, not right at all. You do not assign an expression or formula to the variable, you assign the *current value* of the expression or formula at the time the assignment is executed. Later changes of the input variables will have no effect on the `final` variable's value.

Answer (score -2):

In your current application, your constants are no different than normal computation variables.  You are, indeed, wasting a few CPU cycles by computing what should be a known, declared, *pre*-calculated value to use in your application, effectively missing the point of declaring these values as constants.

Consider this: what would you have to change if your income tax suddenly shot up to 40%?  What about if your bonds went down to 1%?  Constants help you make the change in ideally one place that's clear to see.

Ideally, your constants would represent the percentages you multiply against.

As an example:

```
final double incomeTax = .14;
```

You would then be able to use `incomeTax` in an expression to obtain the actual net amount:

```
double netIncome = income - (incomeTax * income);
```

Comment: @JoshMac: Since you're just beginning, don't break the first rule of optimization: Don't do it.  Your code wouldn't be more optimal anyway since multiplication is more expensive compared to addition.

Comment: `wasting a few CPU cycles`  I think this is what tripped me up; I was under the impression that this would be a more efficient code, since it seemingly wasn't doing as many calculations.  I had actually submitted this lab a lot earlier - a version in which I had written the `final` variables as you've shown - but it apparently got lost, so I rewrote it in what I thought was a more efficient manner. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Haha, I'll be sure to remember that... Any more rules of optimization I should keep on hand?